# get all dates when an event was in progress based upon the event activity log

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, time-series

I got an event log data - with event status timestamps.The dates availabe are only when an actual event had happened.
I want an output where I can know how many events were in progress each day.
ie, if an event started on 1st of Jan, and ended 10th of Jan, the event was in progress from 1st to 10th of Jan.

sample data snapshot

[image]

needed output snapshot.

[image]

data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                ['1/01/2023','Event_a','started'],
                ['5/01/2023','Event_b','started'],
                ['8/01/2023','Event_b','paused'],
                ['10/01/2023','Event_a','Ended'],
                ['11/01/2023','Event_b','started'],
                ['12/01/2023','Event_b','Ended']],
                columns = ['date', 'EventID', 'Event_status'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

I have been able to fill in the missing dates at 'date' and 'event_id' group level, with count of events but stuck with any further progress.

```
df_2 =  df.groupby(['date','issue_id'])[['issue_id']].count()
df_3 = df_2.unstack(['issue_id']).fillna(0).stack(['issue_id'])
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

The example in post cannot convert datetime to desired date. Therefore, following example should be used.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
                ['1/01/2023','Event_a','started'],
                ['5/01/2023','Event_b','started'],
                ['8/01/2023','Event_b','paused'],
                ['10/01/2023','Event_a','Ended'],
                ['11/01/2023','Event_b','started'],
                ['12/01/2023','Event_b','Ended']],
                columns = ['date', 'EventID', 'Event_status'])
```

**Code**

step1. convert datetime to desired date and reshape the table to `df1`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df1 = df.set_index(['date', 'EventID'])['Event_status'].unstack().asfreq('D')
```

df1:

```
EventID     Event_a Event_b
date        
2023-01-01  started NaN
2023-01-02  NaN     NaN
2023-01-03  NaN     NaN
2023-01-04  NaN     NaN
2023-01-05  NaN     started
2023-01-06  NaN     NaN
2023-01-07  NaN     NaN
2023-01-08  NaN     paused
2023-01-09  NaN     NaN
2023-01-10  Ended   NaN
2023-01-11  NaN     started
2023-01-12  NaN     Ended
```

---

step2. After ffilling `df1`, the places where `Started` and the places where `df1` is `paused` or `Ended` are the places where the event is taking place.

```
df1.ffill().eq('started')\
   .add(df1.isin(['paused', 'Ended']))\
   .sum(axis=1)\
   .reset_index()\
   .set_axis(['Date', 'In_progress_Events'], axis=1)
```

output:

```
    Date        In_progress_Events
0   2023-01-01  1
1   2023-01-02  1
2   2023-01-03  1
3   2023-01-04  1
4   2023-01-05  2
5   2023-01-06  2
6   2023-01-07  2
7   2023-01-08  2
8   2023-01-09  1
9   2023-01-10  1
10  2023-01-11  1
11  2023-01-12  1
```

Comment: How Can I make changes to this code to get same numbers but do aggregation at month or Quarterly levels?

Comment: @emudria i thiink you need new question with new desired output